# OS X Trackpads/M-Mouse allow scrolling off edge of the browser (how do we turn it off?)

Tags: macos, browser, scroll, trackpad

I just noticed that in OS X, the use of a trackpad or magic mouse on Chrome or Safari causes the user to be able to scroll off the edge of the page. Here's an image to demonstrate:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hhAp.jpg

Notice the big grey area between the page and the toolbar—this is caused by scrolling off the screen.

What can I write in my code to stop this from happening? I've noticed a couple of sites that do it. Gmail is one, and the other is https://www.apple.com/au/iphone-5c/

The reason I ask is that I'm designing a page that has a similar one page animated scroll to the iPhone 5C page. And every scroll with a trackpad or MM is causing the nav to shift up and down :S.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it (of course I searched for like 20 minutes before posting here, and then as soon as I posted, managed to find the answer).

For anyone also struggling with this issue, here is the answer:

The functionality is called **Inertial Scrolling** and a simple overflow statement selecting html will fix this :)

```
html {
 overflow: hidden;
}
```